# Check how many domains are hosted on a server (Server side)

Tags: linux, networking, domain

How do I check from server side/using bash shell how many domains are hosted on the server?

The goal is to discover how many domains are hosted on the server that are exposed via http/https. (Can be connected to remotely)

The server is running drupal applications.

Comment: I thought I understood the question. Until I got to the last paragraph. Are you sure that what you mention in the last paragraph will do it? ( If it will is that not the answer? ). Please make it clear what you are trying to do. What you have tried. What worked (and why it is unsatisfactory). What did not work.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor removed the last paragraph.

Comment: Have you looked it the configuration file of the web-server?

Comment: Which configuration file are you suggesting I look at and where can I find it/them?

Comment: No Idea. Which web-server are you using?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor httpd + drupal 7 (linux)

Comment: Which `httpd` are you using? (web uses http, servers are called daemons on unix, and have a name ending with a d. Therefore web-server = `httpd`).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your intention is a reverse-lookup of all network interfaces. Be aware that by reverse lookup you may trigger security alarms, since it looks like scanning available resources. Basically you'd enumerate all network devices, get their IPs and do a reverse lookup with the help of (outbound) DNS-services.

The first part is easy:

```
ip addr
```

This lists all network devices and their IP-addresses. With this you can use your favorite DNS-query tool to reverse-lookup, e.g. dig, nslookup, …

Your question for *all domains* is rather general and maybe you don't mean *domain* as in a URL's domain part. A server may expose multitudes of HTTP-based applications, assigned to them based on the Host-parameter of a HTTP-request. Also the server might be a virtual one.

To stay safe, check configuration files on the server only, maybe use `find` or `grep` to get them all. Apache Web Server and Nginx don't differ that much and often use a configuration named http.conf (importing many others). They're often found in /etc/apache or similar.